# $f\in F[x]$ is separable iff its image under a homomorphism is separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification, field-theory, ring-homomorphism

I am trying to prove that $f\in F[x]$ is a separable polynomial iff $\phi (f) \in K[x]$ is a separable polynomial, where $\phi:F\to K$ is a homomorphism of fields.

> $f \in F[x]$ is separable iff $f$ and $Df$ are relatively prime, where $Df$ is the derivative of $f$.

> $f \in F[x]$ is separable iff $(f,Df)$ is the unit ideal.

Here is what I have:

$f\in F[x]$ is separable

$\iff$ any common divisor $p\in F[x]$ of $f$ and $Df$ is a unit in $F[x]$.

$\iff \forall p\in F[x]$, such that $f=pg$ and $Df=ph$ for some $g,h\in F[x]$, $p$ is a unit in $F[x]$

$\iff \forall p\in F[x]$, such that $\phi (f)=\phi(p) \phi(g)$ and $\phi(Df)=\phi(p)\phi(h)$, $\phi(p)$ is a unit in $K[x]$

$\iff$ $\phi(f)$ and $\phi(Df)$ are relatively prime in $K[x]$.

$\iff$ $\phi(f)\in K[x]$ is separable.

> However, I am not convinced by this as I am not sure if $p$ is common divisor of $f$ and $Df$ $\iff$ $\phi(p)$ is a common divisor of $\phi(f)$ and $\phi(Df)$.

What do you think?

Comment: This is true, because if $\phi(p)$ divides $\phi(f)$ and $\phi(Df)$ then it must divide them over the field $\phi(F)$. You can also look at this in a different way. It is pretty clear that $f$ is separable if and only if $\phi(f)$ is separable as a polynomial in $\phi(F)[x]$. But the last condition is equivalent to $\phi(f)$ being separable as a polynomial in $K[x]$. (if $L/K$ is a field extension and $f\in K[x]$ then it is easy to prove that $\gcd_K(f, Df)=1$ iff $\gcd_L(f, Df)=1$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See K. Conrad [Corollary 2.7](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/separable1.pdf).

Forward direction: if we can write $a(x) f(x) + b(x) Df(x) = 1$, then we can apply $\phi$ to get a similar relation on $\phi(f)(x)$ and $\phi (Df)(x)$.

Backwards direction (by contrapositive): suppose that $a(x) | f(x)$ and $a(x) |(Df)(x)$ where $a(x)$ is non-constant. Then $\phi(a)(x)$ is nonconstant and divides both $\phi(f)(x)$ and $\phi(Df)(x)$.